# d3 gradient fill shows black in safari

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, safari

I am creating a bubble chart using d3 v5 and using the following for to create gradient fill:

```
for (let i = 0; i < color.length - 1; i++) {
  const gradient = svg.append('svg:defs')
  .append('svg:linearGradient')
  .attr('id', 'gradient' + i)
  .attr('x1', '0%')
  .attr('y1', '0%')
  .attr('x2', '100%')
  .attr('y2', '100%')
  .attr('spreadMethod', 'pad');

  gradient.append('svg:stop')
    .attr('offset', '0%')
    .attr('stop-color', function(d, j) {
          return '#' + color[i];
      })
    .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

  gradient.append('svg:stop')
    .attr('offset', '100%')
    .attr('stop-color', function(d, j) {
      return '#' + color[i + 1];
    })
    .attr('stop-opacity', 1);
}
```

And then apply it to the circles using:

```
.attr('fill', function(d, j) {
    return 'url(#gradient' + j + ')';
  })
```

The bubble chart works perfectly in firefox and chrome but it appears black in Safari. 
Project in Angular 6.

Comment: why use functions for the stop colors when they are constant? You can put all the gradients in one (1) `defs` element

Comment: you are correct but it won't solve the problem.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this problem?

Comment: @AlmostHandsome Sadly, no.